# Add custom content in user-edit.php page

Tags: wp-admin, settings-api

When I go to edit a user's account located in:

`http://web.site/wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id=ID`

I want to add a custom section with my own information (just text), similar to the [`add_settings_section()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_section) function. However, I believe this is limited to only adding custom sections to the *Settings* menu:

```
Settings
-- General
-- Reading
-- Media
-- Permalinks
```

This is what I have so far which adds my custom section in the *Reading* menu for testing purposes:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_edit_user' );
function wpse_edit_user() {
     add_settings_section( 'user_role', 'User Roles', 'wpse_user_role_section', 'reading' );
}
function wpse_user_role_section() {
    ?>
    <p class="description">Content to my custom section here...</p>
    <?php
}
```

But I do not want to located in *Reading*. How can I have my custom content display in the `user-edit.php` page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it by using [`show_user_profile`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/show_user_profile) and [`edit_user_profile`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edit_user_profile) instead:

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'wpse_237901_user_edit_section', 999 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'wpse_237901_user_edit_section', 999 );

function wpse_237901_user_edit_section() {
    # Code here...
}
```